# How to distinguish it-cleft and extraposition? 'It was Ben that found it' v 'It was clear that Ben found it'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, dummy-it

I have a question about it-cleft and extraposition.
For example the two sentences:

1. It was in the apartment that Ben found something interesting -- a mouse eating cheese.
2. It was obvious that whenever the cake was done, my brother wouldn't eat it unless his father came home.

I am confused about how to identify these two variants. Does it relate to the function of the phrases?
Thank you!

Comment: The most telling difference is that in an _it_ cleft the backgrounnded element is expressed as a relative clause while the foregrounded element functions as complement of "be". There is normally no relative clause in an extraposition construction.

Comment: This question has great answers. Why are people trying to close it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. It is clear [that **Ben ate the cheese**]. <sup>(extraposition)</sup>
2. It is Ben [that **ate the cheese**]. <sup>(*it*-cleft)</sup>

The examples above look very similar. They both have a meaningless dummy pronoun, *it*, as Subject, and they both have similar looking clauses that appear at the end of the sentence. However, although similar, they are not the same.

### **Extrapositions**

We don't like to use clauses as Subjects, because they are difficult for listeners to process. These examples are grammatical, but they're clunky:

- [That **Ben ate the cheese**] is clear.
- [To hang out with you friends] is nice.
- [Whether the chicken got to the other side] is not known.

The extraposition construction is a way of making the sentence more fluid and easier to process. This construction simply puts a meaningless dummy *it*, in the Subject position and shunts the clause down to the end of the sentence where it's easier to process:

3. It's clear [(that) **Ben ate the cheese**].
4. It's nice [to hang out with your friends].
5. It is not known [whether the chicken got to the other side].

### ***It*-clefts**

*It*-clefts break a sentence into two parts. They foreground, or put into focus, one particular phrase and they 'background' the rest of the sentence.

They are called *it*-clefts because they use the pronoun *it* as a meaningless dummy subject of the verb *be*. They are 'clefts' because the rest of the sentence is cleft into two parts, where one appears as the complement of the verb *be* and the rest of the sentence appears as a relative clause at the end of the sentence.

Compare the following:

6. **Boris danced naked**.
7. It was [**Boris**] [that [**danced naked**]].

In (7) the word *Boris* no longer appears as the Subject. Instead it appears as the Complement of *was*. This word is now the focus of the sentence and is more prominent than it is in (6). Here, *that danced naked* is less prominent. It might already have been mentioned in the previous conversation. It definitely is not new news to everybody that someone danced naked here.

Notice, also, that the relative clause after the word *that* has a gap in it where the Subject would normally be:

8. It was Boris that [danced naked.]

This gap corresponds with (it is co-indexed with) the phrase after the verb *be*:

9. It was Boris that [<s>Boris</s> danced naked]
10. It was Boris<sub>i</sub> that [__<sub>i</sub> danced naked]

The phrase after the verb *be* is often contrastive in flavour. You might well understand this sentence to mean something like:

10. It was Boris (not Matt, or someone else) who danced naked.

### **Tests to tell extrapositions from *it*-clefts**

In the following section  [ * ] indicates that the example is ungrammatical.

Firstly, you can always replace a Subject *it* in an extraposition construction with the clause at the end of the sentence:

11. **It** is clear [that Ben ate the cheese]. <sup>(extraposition)</sup>
12. [That Ben ate the cheese] is clear.
13. **It** is Ben [that ate the cheese].<sup>(*it*-cleft)</sup>
14. *[That ate the cheese] is Ben.

Secondly, if the clause at the end of the sentence is a non-finite clause (it doesn't have a tensed verb), then it is an extraposition, not an *it*-cleft:

15. It is not unusual [to see Boris dance naked]. <sup>(no tensed verb-->extraposition)</sup>

Third, if the clause at the end of the sentence is an interrogative clause, it is an extraposition, not an *it*-cleft:

16. It is not clear [whether Rishi danced naked] <sup>(interrogative *whether*-->extraposition)</sup>

Fourth, if the clause at the end of an extraposition is a tensed declarative clause, then you can always omit the word *that*:

17. It is clear that Ben ate the cheese. <sup>(extraposition)</sup>
18. It is clear Ben ate the cheese.
19. It was Ben that ate the cheese. <sup>(*it*-cleft)</sup>
20. *It was Ben ate the cheese. <sup>ungrammatical in standard English</sup>

Fifth, a declarative, tensed clause at the end of an extraposition (excluding the word *that*, if present) will always be a well-formed clause, which could stand as a sentence in its own right:

19. It is clear that [Ben ate the cheese]. <sup>(extraposition)</sup>
20. Ben ate the cheese.
21. It is Ben that [ate the cheese]. <sup>*it*-cleft</sup>
22. *Ate the cheese.

Sixth, the word *that* in an extraposition cannot be replaced by a *wh*-word such as *who* or *which*. In an *it*-cleft it often can be:

23. It is clear **that** Ben ate the cheese. <sup>(extraposition)</sup>
24. *It is clear **who** Ben ate the cheese.
25. It was Ben **that** ate the cheese. <sup>*it*-cleft</sup>
26. It was Ben **who** ate the cheese.

Seventh, an *it*-cleft has a relative clause with a gap in it at the end of the sentence. The gap is co-indexed with the complement of the verb. *be*, as discussed further above. If you take the relative clause and plug it with the complement of the verb *be*, you should get a well-formed sentence:

27. It was [Ben] that [ __ ate the cheese] <sup>*it*-cleft</sup>
28. [Ben] ate the cheese.

There is no gap in the clause at the end of an extraposition, so you can't fill it with the other phrase. But if you try to squish the two together regardless the result is usually ungrammatical:

29. It was [clear] that [Ben ate the cheese].
30. *Clear Ben ate the cheese.
31. *Ben ate the cheese clear.

### **The Original Poster's examples**

> 32. It was in the apartment [that Ben found something interesting -- a mouse eating cheese].

> 33. It was obvious [that whenever the cake was done, my brother wouldn't eat it unless his father came home].

The easiest test we can do here is to see whether we can replace the dummy subject *it* with the *that*-clause that appears at the end of the examples, without changing the meaning:

> 34. [That Ben found something interesting -- a mouse eating cheese] was in the apartment.

This is nonsense and so shows that (32) is an *it*-cleft and not an extraposition. Let's see what happens to (33):

> 35. [That, whenever the cake was done, my brother wouldn't eat it unless his father came home] was obvious.

This is certainly very ugly and ungraceful (which is why we have extrapositions in the first place), but it is grammatical. Of course, the longer the subject clause, the more ungraceful such a sentence will be.

Let's try the omitting *that* test:

> 36 It was obvious, whenever the cake was done, my brother wouldn't eat it unless his father came home.

That seems as good as the original sentence, and suggests it is an extraposition. Lastly, let's try the fifth test. If this is an extraposition, the clause after the word *that* should be able to work as a stand-alone sentence:

> 37. Whenever the cake was done, my brother wouldn't eat it unless his father came home.

This seems to clinch it. This works fine and strongly suggests that the original sentence is an extraposition.

Comment: So can I understand like this, for example, the structure "It BE X that Y", when the X element cannot be deleted, then it's an it-cleft? However, it is an extraposition when the sentence still makes sense even though the X element can be deleted. e.g. "in the apartment" acts as an adjunct in the sample sentence, while "obvious" acts as a complement...?( I am not sure)

Comment: I notice a potential ambiguity in 36 -- does "whenever..." refer to when it became obvious, or when he wouldn't eat it? "that" removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @Barmar I certainly agree. Luckily the original reading is one of the ones still available! I wonder if removing the comma after *done* would force the desired reading?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it would. Conversely, removing the comma before *whenever* would force the alternate reading.

Comment: @Arlo No, I don't think so. If you delete the X, the sentence will. be ungrammatical in both cases.

Comment: *"In (7) the word Boris no longer appears as the Subject. Instead it appears as the Complement of was. "* Are you sure "Boris" is a complement here, and not a [predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)?

Comment: @Stef Well, there's many types of complements, for example direct objects, indirect objects, locative complements and predicative complements (or 'PC's). This one, as you say, is a predicative complement!

Comment: I wonder what you exactly mean by "This gap corresponds with (it is co-indexed with) the phrase after the verb _be_: 9 [...] 10 [...]", according to which, how could _it_-clefts be distinguished from normal relative clauses as in (10') _It's the man that danced naked._ (in response to _Who's that guy you were talking to?_)

Comment: @jk2 There are a load of other tests we could make up for that (if they don't already exist, but I assume they do). For example, the *it* in an *it*-cleft is not referential and so couldn't be replaced by a referential NP like *that there* or *the person standing in the corner* without changing the meaning. Other tests could involve the fact that the 'antecedent' NP and the RC don't form a constituent, although none spring to mind right now.

Comment: I'm asking whether the gap is indeed co-indexed with _Boris_ in 10, as you claim. If it is, what is co-indexed with the gap in (10') _It wasn't Matt that danced naked._?

Comment: @JK2 Your observation is correct that if the clause is negative the identity of the two items, the gap and the subject NP, don't corefer. That is not surprising if you think about it. Take a sentence like *That's my teacher*, where *be* is being used in it's specifying sense. It's natural and accurate to say that a PC in such a sentence describes the subject, and also that the subject NP and the PC NP are co-indexed. However, neither of those is true when the sentence is negated: *That's not my teacher.* That construction is says that the subject ID is *not* the PC one.

Comment: Are you sure it's accurate to say that the subject NP and the PC NP are co-indexed in _That's my teacher_? Because that sounds like a strange thing to say in part because the same cannot be said about any of its positive variants: _That'll be my teacher_; _That'd be my teacher_; _That may be my teacher_; _That must be my teacher_; _That was my teacher_; _That used to be my teacher_; etc. _That_ and _my teacher_ refer to the same person not because they're co-indexed but because the specifying construction in your example happens to make it look like so (but not in any of the variants).

Comment: @JK2 I'm not absolutely 100% sure, but following remarks from GKP, I believe it to be so. I agree with your second and third examples, but that's because they semantically contain an element of negation introduced be the modal concerned. I don't agree with your first and last.

Comment: Even if you (and GKP) define "co-indexing" as encompassing examples like _That's my teacher_, does it necessarily mean that the gap is co-indexed with _Boris_ in _It was Boris that danced naked_? As far as I can tell, all it means is that _It_ and _Boris_ are (or was?) co-indexed. The better way, I suppose, would be to say that the gap is co-indexed with _It_.

Comment: @JK2 No, the one thing that absolutely *cannot* be the case is that the *it* refers to either of the NP’s. It’s just a dummy place-holder or hole-plugger.

Comment: That's the theory. Problem is, the theory cannot explain what the gap is co-indexed with in _It wasn't Matt that danced naked_. So the theory fails.

Comment: See this pair: _It is a serious problem we have here._ vs _This is a serious problem we have here._ In the latter sentence, _this_ can be said to be co-indexed with the gap, can it not?

Comment: @JK2 If you read GKP's comment closely, you'll see that a gap and an NP being co-indexed does not *cause* them to have the same referent it is a way of describing the fact that they have the same referent. So wrt *the theory cannot explain what the gap is co-indexed with in It wasn't Matt that danced naked.*, there is nothing to explain, because there are no two elements that corefer! If you mean "the theory" cannot explain how the listener identifies the semantic subject of the RC, it's because, like with the vast majority of anaphora, it's just pragmatics.

Comment: @JK2 I think you'd enjoy this well-known paper by Paul Postal & GKP: [Expletive noun phrases in subcategorised positions](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Postal-Pullum88.pdf). If my memory serves me correctly, it has clear tests and arguments for identifying non-referential dummy NPs. Re your examples with *this* v *it*, I don't believe that's an *it*-cleft although there are certainly similarities. However, CGEL do say that *it*-clefts can occur with demonstratives as subjects. I agree with you that in the latter case the dem' is probably referential - not that my opinion counts for anything

Comment: You have listed "co-indexing" as a distinguishing feature of it-clefts, and I have argued that "co-indexing" is merely incidental to the construction. Please note that H&P's CGEL doesn't use "co-indexing" at all to explain it-clefts, although it does use it to explain the relative construction (other than it-clefts). // Thanks for the paper. I will read it.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase immediately after 'be' in the cleft construction is always related to a position inside the *that*-clause:

1. It was in the apartment that Ben found something interesting.
   -> Ben found something interesting in the apartment.
2. It was Sam that won the race.
   -> Sam won the race.
3. It was the garage that the storm destroyed.
   -> The storm destroyed the garage.

This is never the case in the extraposition structure: (I'll keep your terminology here, but it's likely that this is not really a case of extraposition in the sense that the term is used in other contexts.)

1. It was obvious that Sam was mad.
   -> * Sam was mad obvious.
2. It was unfortunate that the storm destroyed the garage.
   -> * The storm destroyed the garage unfortunate.

As a consequence of this fact, cleft constructions allow wh-phrases instead of the complementizer 'that':

1. It was Sam who won the race.
2. It was the garage which was destroyed by the storm.

Extraposition doesn't allow this

1. *It was obvious who Sam was mad.
2. *It was unfortunate which the storm destroyed the garage.

In the extraposition structure, the clause can replace the 'it' pronoun in subject position:

1. It was obvious that Sam was mad. -> That Sam was mad was obvious.
2. It was unfortunate that the storm destroyed the garage. -> That the storm destroyed the garage was unfortunate.

This is not possible in the cleft construction:

1. It was in the apartment that Ben found something interesting.
   -> * That Ben found something interesting was in the apartment.
2. It was Sam that won the race.
   -> * That won the race was Sam.
3. It was the garage that the storm destroyed.
   -> * That the storm destroyed was the garage.

Comment: Why call it a _'that_ clause' when it's actually a relative clause that may be introduced by a _wh_ pronoun instead of "that"?

Comment: @BillJ Because the question is about the superficial similarity between extraposition and clefts, both of which involve a *that* clause. Calling it a relative clause presupposes an analysis and makes the diagnostics I'm giving less clear, IMO. Also, depending on what you think a relative clause is, the clause in a cleft may not exactly be a relative clause, although it shares many similar properties. One major difference is that non-restrictive relative clauses (which is the kind of relative clause the cleft would have to be) *can't* use *that*, whereas clefts obviously can.

Comment: Extraposed clauses are not always content clauses (your _that_ clause). They can also be infinitivals or interrogatives. The backgrounded element in an _it_ cleft is always expressed in a relative clause. That's an invariable feature of an _it_ cleft. The relative clause is of the integrated type, though it doesn't have the same modificational properties of a non-cleft integrated relative. Being integrated, it can be introduced by the subordinator "that". Further, it would seem perverse to call the relative clause a _that_ clause since  it may also be a _wh_ relative.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with simpler examples, so the differences stand out. The easiest difference to spot between the two rules is that Extraposition inserts one dummy word, while *It*-cleft inserts three. I'll boldface the inserted words below.

1. **Extraposition**:
   ***It** was obvious [that the cake was done].*
   comes from
   *[That the cake was done] was obvious.*
   Extraposition moves the heavy subject clause [that the cake was done] to the end, leaving dummy ***it*** behind to serve as Subject.
2. ***It*-Cleft**:
   ***It was** [in the apartment] **that** [Ben found them].*
   comes from
   *[Ben found them] [in the apartment].*
   Cleavage breaks the sentence up into two phrases, bracketed above, and emphasizes one of them by using it as the predicate of a clause with *it* as subject and *is* or *was* as an auxiliary, followed by a  relative clause containing the other (de-emphasized) phrase. The *it*, the *be* form, and the *that* complementizer are all inserted by the rule.

The English Extraposition transformation simplifies structure; heavy clauses are easier to understand when they come at the end instead of the beginning of sentences, because English is right-branching.

But all English cleft transformations ([there are several other kinds](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Nobbut.pdf) besides *It*-clefts and *Wh*-clefts) create structure, and thereby make parsing harder. One way to emphasize something is to make it harder to understand -- if people work to understand it, they'll remember it, goes this theory. Speaking as a teacher, I'm not so sure it's correct.

Comment: I think the term  _'that_ clause' is potentially misleading since it may be confused with a _that_ complement clause when in fact it's a relative clause, possibly a _wh_ one.

Comment: I agree with your teacher instincts. Graphic designers like to say, in defense of their hard-to-read font choices, "If it's hard to read, people will read it harder." This is to understand nothing about human nature.

Comment: I have a question. So following the structure: It BE X that Y, when it's extraposition, can I understand that the sentence still makes sense though the X element is deleted? (which acts as an adjunct instead of a complement....?)

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, I've corrected it. Arlo, That isn't the structure of extraposition. What is X? And I can't tell you what you can understand because I don't know what you already think you understand.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. For the sentence "it was obvious that the cake was done", I am assuming that the X element is 'obvious', and the Y element is ‘the cake was done".

Comment: You can't delete _obvious_. It's the main predicate.

Answer (score 2):

**It cleft**:

The simple form of the sentence is

**Ben found something interesting** *in the apartment* -- a mouse eating cheese.

In order to create an “it cleft”, some movement of the elements is required and “it was/is, etc.”, is placed at the start:

It was *in the apartment* [that] **Ben found something interesting** -- a mouse eating cheese.

The website for [eCampus Ontario is helpful.](https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/essentialsoflinguistics2/chapter/identifying-phrases-constituency-tests/)

**Extra position**

Extra position takes place when a relative clause, content clause, adjunct, etc. is moved from its normal position in the sentence, i.e. next to the word it qualifies. Sometimes this is not idiomatic, sometimes it is necessary:

From Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#Examples

> a. Someone **whom we don't know** left a message.
>
> b. Someone left a message **whom we don't know**. - Extraposition of relative clause out of subject
>
> a. Susan said something that nobody expected **more than once**.
>
> b. Susan said something **more than once** that nobody expected. - Extraposition of relative clause out of object
>
> a. Some guy **with red hair** was there.
>
> b. Some guy was there **with red hair**. - Extraposition of prepositional phrase out of subject
>
> a. How frustrated **with their kids** are they?
>
> b. How frustrated are they **with their kids**? - Extraposition of prepositional phrase from predicative adjective phrase
>
> a. %What **that was so entertaining** actually happened?
>
> b. What actually happened **that was so entertaining**? - Extraposition of content clause from subject wh-element
>
> a. %What **that upset everyone** do you think they did?
>
> b. What do you think they did **that upset everyone**? - Extraposition of content clause from object wh-element

Comment: What you've illustrated are not themselves extrapositions, but examples of ENP (Extraposition from Noun Phrase  movement). Extraposition constructions have a  dummy *it* as Subject, just like *it*-clefts.