# What are the grammatical concepts of this sentence?

Tags: verbs, adverbial-phrases

Sentence:

> The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots of gasoline, making it expensive to operate.

I think this is a grammatical sentence but am not sure what the proper concepts are to describe its components. What kind of phrase is "making it expensive to operate"? e.g., is it a participial phrase that modifies the verb phrase "requires lots of gasoline"?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613256/2085).

Answer (score 3):

Labels vary, but "making it expensive to operate" can be called an appendage, a category of [supplement](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar/EB0ABC6005935012E5270C8470B2B740/adjuncts-modifiers-and-supplements/E56EF25F189AD293220FC3C337238FF3) (the other category being an interpolation, which occurs in the middle of a sentence).

A supplement modifies (or [expands](https://www.thoughtco.com/sentence-expanding-grammar-exercises-1691946)) the whole sentence, from which it is structurally separate, reflected in the fact that it is separated from the sentence by punctuation.

In this particular case, it is of the non-finite (participle) clause type.  Other types of include relative clauses, noun phrases or verbless clauses (appositives and absolute phrases) and adjectival, adverbial, and prepositional phrases.

References:

[1](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar/EB0ABC6005935012E5270C8470B2B740/adjuncts-modifiers-and-supplements/E56EF25F189AD293220FC3C337238FF3): A Student's Introduction to English Grammar [Huddleston and Pullum]

[2](https://www.thoughtco.com/sentence-expanding-grammar-exercises-1691946): ThoughtCo: Sentence-expanding Grammar Exercises [Nordquist]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Typo: "other types pf include"

Answer (score 3):

> What kind of phrase is "making it expensive to operate"? e.g., is it a participial phrase that **modifies** the verb phrase "requires lots of gasoline"?

The phrase is headed by the participle *making*, so you could call the phrase a "participial phrase" or a "participial clause" (i.e., a non-finite clause). But I wouldn't say it "modifies" *requires lots of gasoline*. The phrase *making it expensive to operate* isn't combining with *requires lots of gasoline* to form a larger constituent conveying a **modified** meaning. Rather, it's merely explaining a drawback of requiring lots of gasoline. Syntactically, this is expressed with the comma before *making it expensive to operate*. And this kind of phrase is often called a supplement.

Note also that the same meaning can be conveyed with a supplementary relative clause as follows:

> *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots of gasoline, **which makes it expensive to operate**.*

Here, we don't say the relative clause "modifies" *requires lots of gasoline*, because it's not combining with *requires lots of gasoline* to form a larger constituent conveying a **modified** meaning, either.

Answer (score 2):

> *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots of*
> *gasoline,* [*making it expensive to operate*].

You're on the right lines.

I'd say that the bracketed element is simply a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct in clause structure (i.e. a modifier in the VP).

Note that the connective "thus" could be inserted at the start of the clause making it semantically a result adjunct.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145335/discussion-on-answer-by-billj-what-are-the-grammatical-concepts-of-this-sentence); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reduced ***sentence relative clause*** (warning: grammar terms vary) . . .

> Unreduced: *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires
> lots of gasoline, **which makes it expensive to operate**.*
>
> Reduced: *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots
> of gasoline, **making it expensive to operate**.*

Unlike the usual relative, the sentence relative refers not to a noun but to the whole of the preceding proposition.

<sub>See: [Grammaring — Sentential relative clause](https://www.grammaring.com/sentential-relative-clause)</sub>

Comment: "Making it expensive to operate" is not some kind of 'reduced' relative clause, even if there were such a thing (which there isn't), since there is no relativised element anaphorically related an antecedent. It's actually a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct (possibly result) in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ — For the benefit of our guests, you should note that you refer exclusively to *CGEL*’s grammar framework and terminology.

Comment: Not so. The syntax is so obviously different that it makes no sense to call it a 'reduced relative clause'. Relative clauses are either modifiers to a noun or nominal, or supplements (non-modifying, non-integrated adjuncts). By contrast, gerund-participial clauses like the one being discussed here are integrated into clause structure as adjuncts.

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentence

> *The car **is** the best mode of transportation but **requires** lots of gasoline,
>
> **making** it expensive to **operate**.*

there are four main verbs (boldfaced above), which means four clauses, of different types. Since these include subordinate clauses, this is a complex sentence. Since they also include coordinate clauses, it's also a compound sentence. Being both at once makes it a compound-complex sentence. This is all one normally  learns about such sentences in grammar school. But there's plenty more.

First, let's sort out the clauses. As is normal for English compound-complex sentences, many potential constituents don't appear but can be identified nonetheless, like the subject of *Get out of here!* I'll put them (back) in with parentheses marking optionality below:

1. *The car is the best mode of transportation* (first conjoined clause, no deletions)
2. *but (the car/a car/it) requires lots of gasoline,*
   (second conjoined clause, deleted subject from [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/590083/15299), comma for non-restrictive clause)
3. *making it expensive* comes from a non-restrictive relative *which makes it expensive*
   (but the dummy *it* shows something else has been done -- [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/597690/15299) has moved clause (4) to the end)
4. *(for `indef`) to operate (a car)* (this clause is the subject of *(be) expensive* in (3). What's expensive? Operating a car. Who's operating it? We don't care.)

(4) gets pushed to the end to avoid the following train wrecks of  sentences without Extraposition:

- *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots of gasoline, making to operate it expensive*.
- *The car is the best mode of transportation but requires lots of gasoline, which makes to operate it expensive*.

Comment: It's easier and more logical to say "making it expensive to operate" is a gerund-participial clause functioning as an adjunct in clause structure. Note that "thus" could be inserted, making it more specifically a result adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ If you say so. As noted in comments above, you use your own standards for ease, logic, and terminological desirability.

Comment: Extraposition? Surely 'expensive to operate' is one element, a predicate AdjP containing a hollow _to_-infinitival, and 'it' has 'the car' as referent - _The car is **expensive to operate**_. Your last example sentence suggests as much as you've added 'it' into the _to_-infinitival clause; were it extraposition, this would be unnecessary.

Comment: If it's a unit, how come it's got two predicate slots that can be freely substituted: _cheap/easy/dangerous to  operate/buy/sell/talk about_? It's two constructions consisting of two clauses, each with its main predicate (_expensive, operate_). Otherwise you hafta recognize upwards of 100,000 "predicate AdjP" combinations and filter out the ones that don't make sense.

Comment: @John Lawler That's how complementation works - a certain subset of adjectives, when used predicatively, allow hollow _to_-infinitival clauses. Surely you wouldn't argue that there's extraposition in _The car is expensive to operate_ or _The need for lots of gasoline makes the car expensive to operate_; so why argue for it here?

Comment: "Hollow infinitive clauses" Interesting theoretical concept. _The car is expensive to operate_ is not extraposition (which always leaves a dummy _it_ subject), but rather _Tough_-Movement, a minor cyclic movement rule governed by a small group of mostly  adjectival predicates like _tough, expensive, easy,_ etc. You can get the list of predicates that govern  _Tough_-Movement on the web. _Tough_-Movement works just like Subject-Raising, a major rule governed by a large number of predicates, except that, instead of raising its subject, it raises the infinitive's object.